# How do I make it look like the ring here is going around the spire?

Tags: unity, sprites, gameobject, transparency

I have game objects which I'm placing relative to a tilemap using the GameObject brush from the [2D Tilemap Extras](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.2d.tilemap.extras.html) package.

[image: behind]
[image: in front]

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what is necessary to acheive the visual look I'm after, which would be for the blue ring to look as though it is going around the spire, rather than covering it or being covered.

I know when using the internal system of the tilemap, I can configure *Transparency Sort Axis* to allow for half of a tile to be transparent and the other half to not be.

[image: settings sample]

But since I'm using the GameObject brush, I suspect things are being handled a little differently.

Is there any special trick that I can use to have these sprites layer in the way I want described above?

Comment: How have you configured the layer and order in layer properties on the sprite renderers for the spire, back of ring, and front of ring?

Comment: I'm only using one sprite for the entire ring.

Comment: Hint: use two. 

Comment: Is there nothing that can be done with sprite sorting layers and pivot points?  I'm worried about two sprites being a bit fiddly.